# How do I fix this select menu so I can access params via phx-change

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I simply want to capture the data from the drop down menu when a user makes a selection. Ultimately, when a user selects from the Drop Down menu I want to capture the ID of the group item in the event listener

I don't know what to do further.

I expect IO.inspect(params) to show the value when assigned to a specific key in the HTML element (such as name).

```
defmodule AppWeb.GroupLive do
  use AppWeb, :live_view
  alias App.TestBeds
  alias App.Groups


  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    {:ok, assign(socket, testbeds: TestBeds.list_testbeds(), groups: Groups.list_groups())}
  end


  def handle_event("select-group", params, socket)  do  

       IO.inspect params

       {:noreply, socket}
  end


  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div> TestBed Name</div>

   <%= for testbed <- @testbeds do %>
    <div class="name"><%= testbed.name %></div>
      <h2> Select Group </h2>
      <form phx-change="select-group" >
       <select id="group-selection">
        <%= for group <- @groups do %>
          <option value= {"#{group.name}"} name={"#{group.id}"}><%=group.name %></option>
      <% end %>
       </select>
     </form>
   <% end %>

   <div>
    
   </div>
    """
  end
end



params is this:

  View: AppWeb.GroupLive
  Event: "select-group"
  Parameters: %{"_target" => ["undefined"]}
%{"_target" => ["undefined"]}
```

I expect something like

```
  View: AppWeb.GroupLive
  Event: "select-group"
  Parameters: %{"_target" => [name: group-id]}
```

ANSWER
I kinda fixed it but it's still not what I expect

```
  <div class="grid grid-columns-2 grid-flow-col gap-4">

         <%= for testbed <- @testbeds do %>
          
      
        <div class="column-1">

          <div class="name"><%= testbed.name %></div>
    
        </div>

        <div class="column-2">    

            <form phx-change="select-group"  >
               <select id="group-selection"  name="name" data="name" >
                <%= for group <- @groups do %>
                  <option value= {"#{group.id}"} ><%=group.name %></option>
                <% end %>
               </select>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Params now gives me the data with the name attribute as key , but what if I want more than one piece of data? Do I need to put it all in the same string and parse it? I don't think that is right.

```
  View: AppWeb.GroupLive
  Event: "select-group"
  Parameters: %{"_target" => ["name"], "name" => "4"}
%{"_target" => ["name"], "name" => "4"}
[debug] Replied in 409µs
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `phx-change` callback for a form, you will get all *values* for all named fields, be they inputs or selects etc. Just like you had submitted the form.

> what if I want more than one piece of data?

If you refer to more data about each group, you do not really want it to come back from the browser. Store it in the process state and use the id to retrieve it when you need it.

On the other side, if you refer to more data that would be selected via additional inputs, you will have it in other keys of the parameters map. The `name` of the field is the key where you fild the value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this:

Watch my full example in my [github](https://github.com/hackemateninja/PhoenixLiveViewExamples/blob/main/lib/live_view_studio_web/live/athletes_live.ex)

```
 def filter_form(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <form phx-change="filter">
      <div class="filters">
        <select name="sport">
          <%= Phoenix.HTML.Form.options_for_select(
            sport_options(),
            @filter.sport
          ) %>
        </select>
        <select name="status">
          <%= Phoenix.HTML.Form.options_for_select(
            status_options(),
            @filter.status
          ) %>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
    """
  end

  def handle_event("filter", %{"sport" => sport, "status" => status}, socket) do
    filter = %{sport: sport, status: status}

    athletes = Athletes.list_athletes(filter)

    {:noreply, assign(socket, filter: filter, athletes: athletes)}
  end
```